# Version Solving failed for Yo Yo Player - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video, version-control, video-streaming

I have recently decided to use **Yo Yo Player** for livestream video play,

Link: https://pub.dev/packages/yoyo_player

But After adding dependency in my pubspec.yaml file,
It gives me below error :

> Because every version of yoyo_player depends on http ^0.12.2 and
> yourapp depends on http ^0.13.0, yoyo_player is forbidden. So,
> because yourapp depends on yoyo_player ^0.1.0, version solving
> failed. pub get failed (1; So, because yourapp depends on yoyo_player
> ^0.1.0, version solving failed.)

I have tried changing versions but still issue persists.
Can anyone have idea to resolve this?